# javascript audio onload

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I made a javascript audio test. All the function works in Opera FF and Chrome, except audio.oncanplaythrough, and audio.onended (this 2function dont work on Chrome).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var audio = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.ogg");

audio.oncanplaythrough = function(){
audio.play();
}

audio.onended = function(){
alert('ended');
}

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.play();">start</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.pause();">pause</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.volume=prompt('from 0 to 1',0.7)">volume</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.currentTime = 3;">jump</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with onload? Please change title accordingly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`oncanplaythrough` is an event, not a method, and the other event is called `ended` and not `onended`.

So you need to listen for the events and act on them. Try:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() { 
   alert('ended');
}, false);
```

and

```
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
   audio.play();
}, false);
```

Comment: :D there was a space after 'oncanplaythrough '. Now it works, thanks

Comment: So there was (fixed)! Sorry about that. Glad it sorted your problem though.

Comment: This should be `canplaythrough`

Answer (score 4):

Add and play a sound via JavaScript

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'loading.ogg');
audioElement.play();
```

Get the song filepath and duration

```
audioElement.src;
audioElement.duration;
```

Load a sound

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Mogwai2009-04-29_acidjack_t16.ogg');
audioElement.load()
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
  audioElement.play();
  $(".duration span").html(audioElement.duration);
  $(".filename span").html(audioElement.src);
}, true);
```

Stop a song

```
audioElement.pause();
```

Change volume

```
audioElement.volume=0;
```

Play at exactly 35 seconds in the song

```
audioElement.currentTime=35;
audioElement.play();
```

Comment: ... I asked: how to use audio.oncanplaythrough, and audio.onended in Chrome