# HTML5 audio not loading sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have a class `AudioClass` in javascript to play audio as below: (pseudo code)

```
var AudioClass = function() {
     this.audioElement;
     .
     .
     .
     this.load = function(audioSource) {
         this.audioElement = //create Audio, set source etc.
         this.audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
                //some code
         });
     }

     this.play = function(from, to) {
         if(isNaN(this.audioElement.duration)) {    return; }  //line 1
         this.audioElement.currentTime = from/1000;   //line 2   //from & to in milliseconds  
         setTimeout(function() {
               //pause audio.
         }, to-from);
     }
}
```

And I am using the `Audio` as below:

```
/* the below lines are executed on document load. (playing background music) */
var audioInstance = new AudioClass();
audioInstance.load(audioSrc);
audioInstance.play(20000);   //line 3  //20 seconds

/* the below line is used at other places whenever i need sound */
audioInstance.play(40000);   //40 seconds
```

When I am trying to play audio at "line 3", sometimes audio is not loaded by that time, so it is throwing `INVALID_STATE_ERR. DOM EXCEPTION 11 at line 2`. When I checked the audio duration, it was `NaN`. So I added "line 1" to check whether the duration `isNaN()` or not, so that it doesn't try to set `currentTime` until the audio is loaded.

The problem here is sometimes the duration of audio is always NaN. How to fix this?

Comment: FWIW: `Audio` is the name of native HTML5 Audio object. For your custom object, it makes sense to choose another name.

Comment: you're not waiting for the audio to load, create a callback to play the it when it is finished loading

Comment: @Marat Tanalin I am not using "Audio" exactly. It is a psuedo code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a callback to play the audio when it loads. it works whenever you call audio.play in other places because the audio is loaded by then. Here is how i suggest you do it:

```
var Audio = function() {
     this.audioElement;
     .
     .
     .
     this.load = function(audioSource,callback) {
         this.audioElement = //create Audio, set source etc.
         this.audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
                //some code
                if(callback!=null)
                    callback();
         });
     }

     this.play = function(from, to) {
         if(isNaN(this.audioElement.duration)) {    return; }  //line 1
         this.audioElement.currentTime = from/1000;   //line 2   //from & to in milliseconds  
         setTimeout(function() {
               //pause audio.
         }, to-from);
     }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.load(audioSrc,function()
{
audio.play(20000);  
});
```

an answer to a similar question shows how to preload all your audio (in the event you have others) before start using them:
[Proper onload for <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696948/proper-onload-for-audio)

Answer (score 0):

Play the sound in a callback registered to the `loadeddata` or even better, `canplaythrough` event of the `audio` element. (See [javascript audio onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256915/javascript-audio-onload) and similar questions.)